# Analytics v4 implement

Tags: android

I want to add analytics v4 support to my app.I am following this tutorial:http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api

I am copying this class to my app:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

// The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UX-XXXXXXXX-X";

//Logging TAG
private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

public enum TrackerName {
APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
}

HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

public MyApplication() {
super();
}

synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker)
: (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
: analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

}
return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
}
```

But I am getting error for `enum` error:`The member enum TrackerName must be defined inside a static member type`

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial. I had the same problem and I just fixed it.
You only have to create another separate class named MyApplication.
Then don't forget to go into your manifest and add this application element:

```
<application android:name=".YourApplication"...
</application>
```

Good luck!